# How to find simple function representing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I know a recurrent formula of generating sequence of numbers:

$$ T(n, h) =
    \begin{cases}
      1) & [ n ], \textrm{if}\   h = 1 \\
      2) & T(n - h / 2, h / 2) +\\& T(n + h / 2, h / 2) +\\& B(n, h / 2) +\\& T(n, h / 2),\  \textrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases} 
$$

$$
B(n, h) = {
 \begin{cases}
      1) & [ n ], \textrm{if}\ h = 1 \\
   2) & B(n, h / 2) + \\& T(n, h / 2) + \\& B(n - h / 2, h / 2) + \\& B(n + h / 2, h / 2), \textrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
}
$$

where $n$, $h$ are integer numbers. [ 1 2 3 ] denotes sequence of three numbers, sign $+$ denotes concatenation of two sequences (i.e. [ 2 3 4 ] + [ 1 5 0 ] = [ 2 3 4 1 5 0 ]).

How I can simplify its evaluation? Is it possible to represent sequence by a formula `f(i) = ...`? Maybe there is a way to find next number in the sequence given starting parameters of recursion and previous number (with some information about previous state to distinguish between elements with the same value)?

Important note, that recursion starts from invocation of $T$ with $h = 2^m$, $n=h-1 > 0$, where $m > 0$ is integer.

For example, first 100 values for T(63, 64):

```
0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 8, 10, 9, 9, 12, 14, 13, 13, 11, 11, 10, 12, 10, 12, 11, 11, 7, 7, 6, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 6, 9, 9, 8, 10, 4, 6, 5, 5, 8, 10, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 16, 18, 17, 17, 20, 22, 21, 21, 19, 19, 18, 20, 18, 20, 19, 19, 24, 26, 25, 25, 28, 30, 29, 29, 27, 27, 26, 28, 26, 28, 27, 27, 23, 23, 22, 24
```

It this case I am looking for function `f(63,64,5) = 4` or `f(63,64,11) = 2`

Comment: @SK19 I am not considering that case. If you want, you can think about parameter $m$ instead of $h=2^m$ which is descreased by one on each level of recurrency. Initial value of $n$ is also not important, because if we will use 53 instead of 63, we will get the same sequence, where each value will be decreased by 10.

Comment: Ah, apparently I can't read, I'm sorry :(

Comment: @SK19 That's all right. Thank you for interest.